# Accessing all rows in dataset with powershell

Tags: powershell, dataset

I'm looping through a list of sql servers, querying data and creating a dataset which works great.  The dataset is piped to a csv file, which has all the rows.  I'm then trying to create and array from each row then email the results.  The email is being sent but the contents only contain the records from the last server in the list.

```
ForEach ($instance in Get-Content "D:\servers\sqlservers2.txt")
{

$SQLServer = "$instance" #use Server\Instance for named SQL instances! 
$SQLDBName = "msdb"
$SqlQuery = "  

Select
@@servername as [Server],  
j.[name] AS [JobName],  
run_status = CASE h.run_status  
WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed' 
WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded' 
WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry' 
WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled' 
WHEN 4 THEN 'In progress' 
END, 
h.run_date AS LastRunDate,   
h.run_time AS LastRunTime 
FROM sysjobhistory h  
INNER JOIN sysjobs j ON h.job_id = j.job_id  
  WHERE j.enabled = 1   
   and j.name not like 'copytosan'
   and j.name not like 'syspolicy%'
   and j.name not like '%log%'
   AND h.instance_id

   IN 

   (SELECT MAX(h.instance_id)  
       FROM sysjobhistory h GROUP BY (h.job_id))
"



$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = 
$SQLServer; Database =   $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True"


$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

$SqlConnection.Close()
#File is created with all rows from dataset
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Out-File D:\servers\myfiles.csv -Append
}
foreach ($line in $dataset.tables[0])
{
$body += $line
}
#  (Out-String -InputObject $body -Width 100)
Send-MailMessage -To Bob@domain.com -from SQLMAIL@domain.com -Subject    Test12345 -body (Out-String -InputObject $body -Width 100) -SmtpServer  mail@domain.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to nest your second loop.  That way it will loop through the rows of each table instead of only the last table.

```
ForEach ($instance in Get-Content "D:\servers\sqlservers2.txt")
{
    # code
    foreach ($line in $dataset.tables[0])
    {
        $body += $line
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple.  Thank you